# Elastic Beanstalk create got install_dependencies error when installing requirements.txt

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, requirements.txt

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-activity.log
-------------------------------------
  Collecting argparse==1.2.1 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 10))
    Downloading argparse-1.2.1.tar.gz (69kB)
  Collecting distribute==0.6.24 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 11))
    Downloading distribute-0.6.24.tar.gz (620kB)
      Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-build-yng8yda8/distribute/setuptools/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
          from setuptools.extension import Extension, Library
        File "/tmp/pip-build-yng8yda8/distribute/setuptools/extension.py", line 2, in <module>
          from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
        File "/tmp/pip-build-yng8yda8/distribute/setuptools/dist.py", line 103
          except ValueError, e:
                           ^
      SyntaxError: invalid syntax

      ----------------------------------------
  Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-yng8yda8/distribute
  You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
  You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
  2017-09-05 02:39:47,289 ERROR    Error installing dependencies: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 22, in main
      install_dependencies()
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 18, in install_dependencies
      check_call('%s install -r %s' % (os.path.join(APP_VIRTUAL_ENV, 'bin', 'pip'), requirements_file), shell=True)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 541, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1 (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
caused by: Collecting Flask==0.10.1 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 1))
    Downloading Flask-0.10.1.tar.gz (544kB)
  Collecting Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.0 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 2))
    Downloading Flask-SQLAlchemy-2.0.tar.gz (93kB)
  Collecting Flask-WTF==0.10.3 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 3))
    Downloading Flask-WTF-0.10.3.tar.gz (247kB)
  Collecting Jinja2==2.7.3 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 4))
    Downloading Jinja2-2.7.3.tar.gz (378kB)
  Collecting MarkupSafe==0.23 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 5))
    Downloading MarkupSafe-0.23.tar.gz
  Collecting PyMySQL==0.6.3 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 6))
    Downloading PyMySQL-0.6.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (63kB)
  Collecting SQLAlchemy==0.9.8 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 7))
    Downloading SQLAlchemy-0.9.8.tar.gz (4.1MB)
  Collecting WTForms==2.0.1 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 8))
    Downloading WTForms-2.0.1.zip (444kB)
  Collecting Werkzeug==0.9.6 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 9))
    Downloading Werkzeug-0.9.6.tar.gz (1.1MB)
  Collecting argparse==1.2.1 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 10))
    Downloading argparse-1.2.1.tar.gz (69kB)
  Collecting distribute==0.6.24 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 11))
    Downloading distribute-0.6.24.tar.gz (620kB)
      Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-build-yng8yda8/distribute/setuptools/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
          from setuptools.extension import Extension, Library
        File "/tmp/pip-build-yng8yda8/distribute/setuptools/extension.py", line 2, in <module>
          from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
        File "/tmp/pip-build-yng8yda8/distribute/setuptools/dist.py", line 103
          except ValueError, e:
                           ^
      SyntaxError: invalid syntax

      ----------------------------------------
  Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-yng8yda8/distribute
  You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
  You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
  2017-09-05 02:39:47,289 ERROR    Error installing dependencies: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 22, in main
      install_dependencies()
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 18, in install_dependencies
      check_call('%s install -r %s' % (os.path.join(APP_VIRTUAL_ENV, 'bin', 'pip'), requirements_file), shell=True)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 541, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1 (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)


[2017-09-05T02:39:47.296Z] INFO  [3093]  - [Application deployment app-80f3-170904_193745@1/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03deploy.py] : Activity failed.
[2017-09-05T02:39:47.296Z] INFO  [3093]  - [Application deployment app-80f3-170904_193745@1/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook] : Activity failed.
[2017-09-05T02:39:47.296Z] INFO  [3093]  - [Application deployment app-80f3-170904_193745@1/StartupStage0] : Activity failed.
[2017-09-05T02:39:47.296Z] INFO  [3093]  - [Application deployment app-80f3-170904_193745@1] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application deployment - Command CMD-Startup failed
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.125Z] INFO  [3367]  - [CMD-TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.125Z] INFO  [3367]  - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Starting activity...
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.125Z] INFO  [3367]  - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Completed activity.
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.125Z] INFO  [3367]  - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.125Z] INFO  [3367]  - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.385Z] INFO  [3367]  - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs/TailLogs] : Completed activity.
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.385Z] INFO  [3367]  - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs] : Completed activity. Result:
  CMD-TailLogs - stage 0 - Command CMD-TailLogs stage 0 completed
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.386Z] INFO  [3367]  - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsAfter] : Starting activity...
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.386Z] INFO  [3367]  - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsAfter] : Completed activity.
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.386Z] INFO  [3367]  - [CMD-TailLogs] : Completed activity. Result:
  CMD-TailLogs - Command CMD-TailLogs succeeded
[2017-09-05T02:52:36.034Z] INFO  [3720]  - [CMD-TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2017-09-05T02:52:36.035Z] INFO  [3720]  - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Starting activity...
[2017-09-05T02:52:36.035Z] INFO  [3720]  - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Completed activity.
[2017-09-05T02:52:36.035Z] INFO  [3720]  - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2017-09-05T02:52:36.035Z] INFO  [3720]  - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...



-------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-commandprocessor.log
-------------------------------------
  Collecting MarkupSafe==0.23 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 5))
    Downloading MarkupSafe-0.23.tar.gz
  Collecting PyMySQL==0.6.3 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 6))
    Downloading PyMySQL-0.6.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (63kB)
  Collecting SQLAlchemy==0.9.8 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 7))
    Downloading SQLAlchemy-0.9.8.tar.gz (4.1MB)
  Collecting WTForms==2.0.1 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 8))
    Downloading WTForms-2.0.1.zip (444kB)
  Collecting Werkzeug==0.9.6 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 9))
    Downloading Werkzeug-0.9.6.tar.gz (1.1MB)
  Collecting argparse==1.2.1 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 10))
    Downloading argparse-1.2.1.tar.gz (69kB)
  Collecting distribute==0.6.24 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 11))
    Downloading distribute-0.6.24.tar.gz (620kB)
      Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-build-yng8yda8/distribute/setuptools/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
          from setuptools.extension import Extension, Library
        File "/tmp/pip-build-yng8yda8/distribute/setuptools/extension.py", line 2, in <module>
          from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
        File "/tmp/pip-build-yng8yda8/distribute/setuptools/dist.py", line 103
          except ValueError, e:
                           ^
      SyntaxError: invalid syntax

      ----------------------------------------
  Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-yng8yda8/distribute
  You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
  You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
  2017-09-05 02:39:47,289 ERROR    Error installing dependencies: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 22, in main
      install_dependencies()
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 18, in install_dependencies
      check_call('%s install -r %s' % (os.path.join(APP_VIRTUAL_ENV, 'bin', 'pip'), requirements_file), shell=True)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 541, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1 (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)


[2017-09-05T02:39:47.296Z] ERROR [3093]  : Command CMD-Startup failed!
[2017-09-05T02:39:47.297Z] INFO  [3093]  : Command processor returning results: 
{"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"(TRUNCATED)...)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py\", line 541, in check_call\n    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)\nCalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1. \nHook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI","returncode":1,"events":[{"msg":"Your requirements.txt is invalid. Snapshot your logs for details.","severity":"ERROR","timestamp":1504579187},{"msg":"Error installing dependencies: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1","severity":"SYSTEM","timestamp":1504579187}]}],"truncated":"true"}
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.119Z] DEBUG [3367]  : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.119Z] DEBUG [3367]  : Checking if the command processor should execute...
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.122Z] DEBUG [3367]  : Checking whether the command is applicable to instance (i-0a00556dc193b37c2)..
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.122Z] INFO  [3367]  : Command is applicable to this instance (i-0a00556dc193b37c2)..
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.122Z] DEBUG [3367]  : Checking if the received command stage is valid..
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.122Z] INFO  [3367]  : No stage_num in command. Valid stage..
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.122Z] INFO  [3367]  : Received command CMD-TailLogs: {"execution_data":"{\"aws_access_key_id\":\"ASIAJK6RO3FVZHZMBKDQ\",\"signature\":\"1N0kAs7HSzFzle3vbfQY50AC35w=\",\"security_token\":\"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\",\"policy\":\"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\"}","instance_ids":["i-0a00556dc193b37c2"],"data":"e1eae1c3-91e3-11e7-ae1d-f7e957ce8124","command_name":"CMD-TailLogs","api_version":"1.0","resource_name":"AWSEBAutoScalingGroup","request_id":"e1eae1c3-91e3-11e7-ae1d-f7e957ce8124"}
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.122Z] INFO  [3367]  : Command processor should execute command.
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.122Z] DEBUG [3367]  : Storing current stage..
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.122Z] DEBUG [3367]  : Stage_num does not exist. Not saving null stage. Returning..
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.122Z] DEBUG [3367]  : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.122Z] DEBUG [3367]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_ContainerConfigFileContent||commands..
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.123Z] DEBUG [3367]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_API||_Commands..
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.123Z] INFO  [3367]  : Found enabled addons: ["logstreaming", "logpublish"].
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.124Z] INFO  [3367]  : Updating Command definition of addon logstreaming.
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.124Z] INFO  [3367]  : Updating Command definition of addon logpublish.
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.124Z] DEBUG [3367]  : Loaded definition of Command CMD-TailLogs.
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.124Z] INFO  [3367]  : Executing CMD-TailLogs
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.125Z] INFO  [3367]  : Executing command: CMD-TailLogs...
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.125Z] INFO  [3367]  : Executing command CMD-TailLogs activities...
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.125Z] DEBUG [3367]  : Setting environment variables..
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.125Z] INFO  [3367]  : Running AddonsBefore for command CMD-TailLogs...
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.125Z] DEBUG [3367]  : Running stages of Command CMD-TailLogs from stage 0 to stage 0...
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.125Z] INFO  [3367]  : Running stage 0 of command CMD-TailLogs...
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.125Z] DEBUG [3367]  : Loaded 1 actions for stage 0.
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.125Z] INFO  [3367]  : Running 1 of 1 actions: TailLogs...
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.385Z] INFO  [3367]  : Running AddonsAfter for command CMD-TailLogs...
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.386Z] INFO  [3367]  : Command CMD-TailLogs succeeded!
[2017-09-05T02:42:41.386Z] INFO  [3367]  : Command processor returning results: 
{"status":"SUCCESS","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"SUCCESS","msg":"","returncode":0,"events":[{"msg":"[Instance: i-0a00556dc193b37c2] Successfully finished tailing 5 log(s)","severity":"INFO","timestamp":1504579361386}]}]}
[2017-09-05T02:52:36.028Z] DEBUG [3720]  : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2017-09-05T02:52:36.029Z] DEBUG [3720]  : Checking if the command processor should execute...
[2017-09-05T02:52:36.031Z] DEBUG [3720]  : Checking whether the command is applicable to instance (i-0a00556dc193b37c2)..
[2017-09-05T02:52:36.031Z] INFO  [3720]  : Command is applicable to this instance (i-0a00556dc193b37c2)..
[2017-09-05T02:52:36.031Z] DEBUG [3720]  : Checking if the received command stage is valid..
[2017-09-05T02:52:36.031Z] INFO  [3720]  : No stage_num in command. Valid stage..
[2017-09-05T02:52:36.031Z] INFO  [3720]  : Received command CMD-TailLogs: {"execution_data":"{\"aws_access_key_id\":\"ASIAIHB5G7TBBX3VH2YQ\",\"signature\":\"rBMjKexmjcnDM2Y3cj5Rij86nkA=\",\"security_token\":\"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\",\"policy\":\"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\"}","instance_ids":["i-0a00556dc193b37c2"],"data":"44a1eb93-91e5-11e7-980c-b30710565f73","command_name":"CMD-TailLogs","api_version":"1.0","resource_name":"AWSEBAutoScalingGroup","request_id":"44a1eb93-91e5-11e7-980c-b30710565f73"}
[2017-09-05T02:52:36.031Z] INFO  [3720]  : Command processor should execute command.
[2017-09-05T02:52:36.031Z] DEBUG [3720]  : Storing current stage..
[2017-09-05T02:52:36.031Z] DEBUG [3720]  : Stage_num does not exist. Not saving null stage. Returning..
[2017-09-05T02:52:36.031Z] DEBUG [3720]  : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2017-09-05T02:52:36.032Z] DEBUG [3720]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_ContainerConfigFileContent||commands..
[2017-09-05T02:52:36.032Z] DEBUG [3720]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_API||_Commands..
[2017-09-05T02:52:36.033Z] INFO  [3720]  : Found enabled addons: ["logstreaming", "logpublish"].
[2017-09-05T02:52:36.034Z] INFO  [3720]  : Updating Command definition of addon logstreaming.
[2017-09-05T02:52:36.034Z] INFO  [3720]  : Updating Command definition of addon logpublish.
[2017-09-05T02:52:36.034Z] DEBUG [3720]  : Loaded definition of Command CMD-TailLogs.
[2017-09-05T02:52:36.034Z] INFO  [3720]  : Executing CMD-TailLogs
[2017-09-05T02:52:36.035Z] INFO  [3720]  : Executing command: CMD-TailLogs...
[2017-09-05T02:52:36.035Z] INFO  [3720]  : Executing command CMD-TailLogs activities...
[2017-09-05T02:52:36.035Z] DEBUG [3720]  : Setting environment variables..
[2017-09-05T02:52:36.035Z] INFO  [3720]  : Running AddonsBefore for command CMD-TailLogs...
[2017-09-05T02:52:36.035Z] DEBUG [3720]  : Running stages of Command CMD-TailLogs from stage 0 to stage 0...
[2017-09-05T02:52:36.035Z] INFO  [3720]  : Running stage 0 of command CMD-TailLogs...
[2017-09-05T02:52:36.035Z] DEBUG [3720]  : Loaded 1 actions for stage 0.
[2017-09-05T02:52:36.035Z] INFO  [3720]  : Running 1 of 1 actions: TailLogs...
```

Comment: Is this a spam or what?

Answer (score 1):

You should add your requirements.txt in same question. Have you added setuptools in your requirements.txt if no then add & try with that.